# Multiple fixed size div's auto line break

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

My Goal is to have a DIV that contains other fixed sized DIVs. Those DIVs should contain a line break (only) if necessary. So it should look like the following:

No line breaks necessary:

```
_______________________________
|   ____   ____   ____        |
|   |__|   |__|   |__|        |
|                             |
|                             |
|_____________________________|
```

Line break necessary:

```
_______________________________
|   ____   ____   ____   ____ |
|   |__|   |__|   |__|   |__| |
|   ____                      |
|   |__|   ...                |
|_____________________________|
```

Currently, the best I could come up is the following:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    ...
</div>

<style>
#outer {
    overflow: auto;
}
#outer div {
    display: inline;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#outer div p {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    Display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

Does anybody have an idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried with flexbox? - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @ThomasSparber it's working fine as i just added few css code **http://jsfiddle.net/44rbrh4r/1/**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hope this will help you and resolve your query, let me know any issues**
@thomas

```css
#outer {
    overflow: auto;
  border:1px solid #ff0000;
  padding:10px;
}
#outer div {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin:0px 1% 2% 1%;
}
#outer div p {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin:0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  <div>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  <div>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  <div>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  <div>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  <div>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  <div>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  <div>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  <div>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  <div>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/44rbrh4r/)**

```
#outer div {
    display: inline-block; / Use inline-block */
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#outer div p {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here your code is working fine i have tried to change the display inline-block to the div to make the block in a row

```css
#outer {
    overflow: auto;
}
#outer div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 32px;
    margin: 15px;
}
#outer div p {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
     <div>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the demo working code for this

**[Demo code](http://jsfiddle.net/44rbrh4r/2/)**